# Send multiple return values from python to react when posting data

Tags: python, reactjs

Let's say I have a post request like this:

```
addPerson() {
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/addPerson", {personArray})
      .then(res => {
         console.log("Persons added")
      })
  }
```

So I'm passing a list of persons to python and want to add those persons to the database.
This is for example the python code:

```
@app.route("/addPerson", methods=["POST"])
def addPersonMethod():

    personArray = request.json.get('personArray')

    for person in personArray:
          ....code that adds a person to the database....

           return a value to the frontend after a person has been added

    return "All persons added"
```

Now I wanna let the user know how many persons have been added so that I can display something like "4 of 1400 persons have been added" in the frontend and update the number of added persons every time a new person gets added to the database (so after every iteration of the for loop). This is important for my programm because it could take very long if e.g. 100.000 persons should be added. Because it could take very long, the user should see how long it could take to upload all persons to the database.

Is there a way to return for example an integer value to the frontend after every iteration of the for loop?

Comment: just a suggestion, i think you should use sockets to send updates from server to client, and handle the updates from the client by updating the user interface, not sure how to do it between react and python but i think a python implementation of SocketIO client exists somewhere on github

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already have an entire backend application so I think it's pretty hard to use sockets, isn't it? Or could I for example leave my entire backend code how it is and  just add one socket method which can send information to the frontend?